# JSP with handlebar accessing array not working

Tags: spring, jsp, handlebars.js, jstl

I'm trying to access data from my model within my handlebar (which is a template in my jsp page)

I'll give a small example of what i'm trying to get to work.

the json contains the following:

```
 var data = {"residentId": 0,"hoedanigheid": "valueOfhoedanigheid1", "firstName": "Jos", "lastName": "White"};
```

I also added the residentList with spring webflow It's inside a FlowHandler:
addResidentInfoFlowFormHandler.java:

```
residentsInfoFormModel.getModelMap().addAttribute("residentList", residentFormModels);
```

residentFormModel:

```
@Getter
@Setter
private Long residentInfoId;

@Getter
@Setter
private Long residentInfoTypeId;

@Getter
@Setter
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = DATE_FORMAT)
private Date startDate;

@Getter
@Setter
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = DATE_FORMAT)
private Date endDate;


@Getter
@Setter
private BewonerFormArrayList residentList = new ResidentFormArrayList(); // I need to access this list!
```

The handlebar contains the following (here's where stuff go wrong):

```
<script id="editResidentTmpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<c:set var="residentId" value="{{residentId}}"/>
<c:set var="residentList" value="${modelMap.residentList}"/>
<c:set var="resident" value="${residentList[residentId]}"/>
<p>${residentId}</p>
<p>{{firstName}}</p>
${residentList[0].firstName}
${residentList[1].firstName}
<!-- The 2 following lines do not work!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->
${resident}
${residentList[residentId].firstName} 
</script>
```

The weird thing is that everything works, but the last line of code does not.
I can litterly use every small part of the code. But using the constant together with the list is not working. I'm just trying to do a simple thing: getting the object that's in the list.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Where is the code showing where you are setting those variables? If the last two don't work, it's probably because you have not set them.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  But I think I already figured it out... Handlebars are clientside & jstl is server side. I think the combination will never work. It explains why I could see only parts of my data in jstl/handlebar seperately. But not the combination of jstl and Handlebar...